# Automatic open WhatsApp directly using UIDocumentINteractionController without presenting the other apps

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uidocumentinteraction, socialshare

I'm developping share image to the other apps, including `WhatsApp`.
I'm using this code and it works.

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"whatsapp://app"]]){
    UIImage *image = [self processImage:sender];

    NSString *savePath  = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/whatsAppTmp.wai"];

    [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) writeToFile:savePath atomically:YES];


    _documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:savePath]];
    _documentInteractionController.delegate = self;
    _documentInteractionController.UTI = @"net.whatsapp.image";
    [_documentInteractionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES];


}else {
    [self showAlertTitle:@"WhatsApp not installed." message:@"Your device has no WhatsApp installed."];
}
```

The problem is, when I run this code, `documentInteractionController` presents the other options apps like this [image](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/iv5ZpX1SPiR2-WV8dGs1CgCJaW-R2iU6-V77geCDt8HM87RMtmJwjzmd0itzS3-Gn7d1r02HFPETEbpO-bWueNeSD6A-l6afzD6PbMb04JLzPRK9OK1yGNC4JI2GIUReUaDKfBtokoGb0MU6qnJO_ilK1_tY2AWeNT_aTl2WxhAJR0UtLWsbKw9cnk0XJ80St8H7tKNBnsvC26lfTPYB0cCaDJryrjKAe1o_d5WSXIJbbFxZkI2S0Kr8OBPuDLYkuQ9S6S5ANT2sPuDQ1Mn8MuY_iB-J62jAFeXvKhpzzMwr6YHgRG8w9NIJoobihDQCi3lfOtiOiQPqI8JaKWF6YHELDGugWgn9e1j-g6w2SpEzOQJAD3MQCCIrsUiBCODs5zEDJFe1-ty4W6TaWC_jWEWbTUtWm8-yr1qzpX2WvSFcbsURbVM2bj5eSTmQyCV82FX62BbHKjRRgW-keqaCSKvt7Z6x3HcF_Kxg2A2siXPaZdiT2KLYLIV8myzpEfXZvFGzt8MkTB14UN_XMTMQGS-jYT2Hbjga5-QoKnZm5UX_8rskzu5zhKVAvXSzCY2PFNtzb1Y9A2a3y1tn7Q8WNIlIxRrWihEbOe2lcgND2dOWa2sq=w640-h1136-no), so I must pick WhatsApp first before it open WhatsApp application.

Can I select Whatsapp App to share the file without presenting the menu for choosing? In other words, can I avoid `presentOpenInMenuFromRect` ?

I`m using iOS 9 and this issue happen also with my Instagram post

Answer (score 2):

**Yes.** you can write [this](https://gist.github.com/BenBarahona/a8e4b71a62add9ba1ae6) code. After run code do the following.

Step:1 Add LSApplicationQueriesSchemes in Info.plist

Step:2 Add whatsapp in items.

Comment: i can't use this method because i must send image data, not text. As i know, custom URL Scheme doesn't support image data yet.

Comment: How to implement Share extension method in code? 
i think Share Extension refers to documentInteractionController method.

Comment: in step 1: i have tried those code and it is actually the same code as i used before, still, it launched documen interaction menu first before i can launch my whatsApp
in step 2: i have add whatsapp in items already

Comment: I have same problem. I want to share a image on whatsapp. This code is just opening interaction menu. Maybe whatsapp removed this feature?